# Array index out of range swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift3, indexoutofboundsexception, fatal-error

I am getting the angle between adjacent points in hull array and storing it in angles array.But getting fatal error for index out of range. What am I doing wrong here?`var angles = [Double]()
    for index in 1..<hull.count {
        angles[index-1] = Double(hull[index-1].angleToPoint(comparisonPoint: hull[index]))

    }`

Comment: Well `angles` is empty... you probably meant to append rather than subscript (`map` would also be a good option).

Comment: var angles = [Double]()
                for index in 0..<hull.count{
                    angles.append(Double(hull[index].angleToPoint(comparisonPoint: hull[index+1])))
                    
                }

Comment: I am getting index out of range on this as well Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use enumerated for index and element at the same loop:

```
angles = []
for (i, h) in hull.enumerated() {
    if i == 0 { continue }
    let angle = Double(hull[i-1].angleToPoint(comparisonPoint: h)) ?? 0
    angles.append(angle)
}
```

Comment: Double(h[i-1]) is giving me error
Actually, my task is complex because I have to change values in one array based on another array. And these arrays are not of same size.

Comment: Sorry, it's an obviously error of h[i-1], it should be hull[i-1], I updated the answer to make it work.